# executing a shell script on a server from a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shell, ssh

I have a program on a remote server that publishes data onto the database.
This program has to be executed with root permissions for it to function properly.
and i have to start its execution from a webpage. i.e., if an event fires, this script's execution should start( for now consider the event as click of a button)

I know this can be done using php or other server side scripting languages but I am forced to use javascript or other related technologies like AJAX, jquery etc..

I was concerned about the security so this is what i planned.

**I will ssh into the server using a key pair,
then have a shell script that takes control as root and start execution of the program.**

I don't want to parse or print any output on my webpage.
just starting the script would do the job.

can someone help me out with this please..

Thanks!

Comment: Javascript,(which includes jQuery) is a client-side technology. It won't be able to do anything on a server without some server-side system to do the work. You might choose to use some form of AJAX call, or simply make an HTTP GET (or POST) request. You won't be able to connect with SSH using just Javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JavaScript does not have support for TCP/IP sockets, so it is really impossible to do this *purely* in JavaScript.  However, you could accomplish this using AJAX web sockets (like WebShell and AnyTerm do) and have the server handle and authenticate the session locally.

Another option, should you absolutely require everything to be done on the client-side, would be to use a java applet run in the user's browser.  Obviously this applet could function as a terminal shell, but per your needs, you could very easily make the applet open, authenticate, run the script then pass back a confirmation the script started OK.

Comment: ok.

I am trying to solve this steb by step.

first i creates a key pair using ssh-keygen

then i copied my public key to the remote host using 
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host

but when i am trying to execute a sudo su or sudo -i command using that shell script, I am not able to...

I am new to programming in linux and I don't know what's happening.

and my remote machine is a raspberry pi and it has the root user disabled .. so I cant ssh as a root.

Comment: Alright, not a problem; no one here was an expert when they started out.  So basically, from what I can tell, it seems like you haven't given the user permission to operate as a superuser.  What version of Linux are you running on your RasPi?  If you are running Ubuntu, or a variant thereof, You can solve this by running 'sudo add <USERNAME> sudo'.  Essentially what you are doing is adding the user USERNAME to the sudo group.  This will then give them permission to run commands as a superuser.

Comment: Another point, as remote access is disabled for root (as it should be!) you will have to complete the above step directly on the RasPi, not through SSH.  Also, you can edit the superdoers file, with the visudo command, if you want to further modify the privileges of the root, sudo and admin groups.  Cheers!

Comment: the version of linux on rPi is Wheezy.
but this is what i find in the visudo file
#includedir /etc/sudeores.d
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

so that's how it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't ssh into the box as root you need to set up an executable script that will run as user root that can be called from the regular user you ssh in as. To do this:

chown root executable

chgrp root executable

chmod 4755 executable

Unfortunately for security reasons executable can't be a shell script (under Linux anyway) so you need to write a short C program containing lots of system() calls. Compile this and you should be away. Of course the C program could be as simple as

system("./executable");

But that would be a huge security hole on a regular server anyways. If the C program takes parameters for substitution then you need to validate those or security could be compromised. At the very least - check and exit without doing anything if any parameter contains an embedded ';'